# Replace files with others from other folder matched by first token in filename

Tags: linux, regex, batch-rename

Lets say I have two folders:

```
ls /A/
    01 - IncorrectName.flac
    02 - otherincorrect.flac

ls /B/
    01 - CorectName.flac
    02 - Othercorrect.flac
```

How would I move the files from dir A to B, but using the filenames from dir B?

Could I be  doing this automatically with `$ mv /A/01 - IncorrectName.flac /B/01 - CorrectName.flac` ?

The first 5 characters of all filenames are always "NN - "

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure I understand what you want, but this could be it in bash:

```
#! /bin/bash
for file in "$1"/[0-9][0-9]*.flac ; do
    newname="$2"${file#"$1"}
    newname=${newname:0:5+${#2}}
    mv "$file" "$newname"*
done
```

**Update**: should work with command line arguments. The trick was the length of the string was not constant anymore, hence `${#2}`.

Comment: I want to make use of the existing filenames from directory B while renaming/moving the files in directory A, matching a file in A to the name in B by means of the first 5 characters of the filenames. That is, the track number of these flac files.

Comment: Bash complains of "Bad substitution", my folder names have spaces, but moving them to just A and B has not had any effect, the problem remains.

Comment: Hi even with the typo replaced I get "Bad substitution"

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: Strange. Are there any other files in the directories? In such a case, you should use some safer wildcard instead of `*`, e.g. `[0-9][0-9]*.flac`.

Comment: Can this be modified so I can pass in the two directories as arguments to the script? I tried this replaceing /A/* with $1/* and /B with $2 but I get the same error

Comment: Actually it works perfectly with A & B! thank you. My folder names have spaces and [ ] characters in them, maybe that is causing the fault?

Comment: Then just quote them, `"$1"` and so on.